# Cannot render an xml layout with LayoutInfalter. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: android

I need to show a layout from xml file and draw some vector based image on top of that. If code below is executed then everything is shown but the layout. Why? What I'm doing wrong?

```
public class About extends Activity 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.about); 
    setContentView(new GraphicsView(this));
}

public class GraphicsView extends View
{
    public GraphicsView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);                 
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        Context context;
        context=getContext();

        View aview; 

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
        aview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about, null);                 

        aview.draw(canvas);

        Path circle = new Path();
        Paint cPaint = new Paint(); 
        cPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        circle.addCircle(150, 150, 100, Direction.CW);
        canvas.drawPath(circle, cPaint);
        cPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath("Some stupid text", circle, 0, 20, cPaint);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After inflating the View you need to measure it and lay it out to give it a size so it can be properly drawn. You should call aview.measure() and aview.layout() before calling aview.draw().

Note that you should **NEVER** inflate views from onDraw(). It is very expensive and wasteful. Similarly, you should NEVER create paints or paths inside onDraw().

Answer (score 0):

There is an another answer from another forum:

FrameLayout:

```
 public class About extends Activity 
 { 
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
       setContentView(R.layout.about);

       GraphicsView drawing = new GraphicsView(this);

       FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
       container.addView(drawing);
    } 

    public class GraphicsView extends View 
    { 
       public GraphicsView(Context context) 
       { 
          super(context);                 
       } 
       @Override 
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
       { 
          Path circle = new Path(); 
          Paint cPaint = new Paint(); 
          cPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY); 
          circle.addCircle(150, 150, 100, Direction.CW); 
          canvas.drawPath(circle, cPaint); 
          cPaint.setColor(Color.RED); 
          canvas.drawTextOnPath("Some stupid text", circle, 0, 20, cPaint); 
       } 
    } 
 }
```

And then here comes XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="10dip" 
    android:id="@+id/container"> 
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/about_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/about_text" />
</FrameLayout>
```